# How to pass initial parameters to a Wakanda component?

Tags: javascript, parameters, components, wakanda

I'm creating a Wakanda component and I need set its initial state by passing parameters ot it.

How could I pass initial parameters to Wakanda?

Answer (score 2):

You pass your parameters in the `userData` property.

```
$$('component1').loadComponent({ path: "dialog.waComponent", userData: { myParameter: "Specific data"} });
```

Inside the component, you receive the passed parameters in the `this.load(data)` function **inside the constructor** part of the component.

*Example:*

```
this.load = function (data) {
        this.myParameter = data.userData.Parameter;
}
```

This link provides a more comprehensive description:
http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda-Widgets-Instance-API/Component.201-854895.en.html